# Passing through variable names on attached c# files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Site.master file with a Site.master.cs attached to it

**This bit of code works:**

```
<%
    var example = "text";
%>

<%=example%>
```

How do I make it so I can define "example" in the C# file and call the variable through:

```
<%=example%>
```

in the Site.master file?

Comment: You should declare it as `public` or `protected` in the `Site.master.cs` file.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! @PradeepKumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public property in your .cs file like

```
public string example {get;set;}
```

in your load event assign value to it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     example = "Some example";
}
```

Then use it in aspx page

```
<%=example%>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a property. It could just be a field, which makes initialization easier, ex: `public string example = "some example";` or in C# 6 you can take advantage of [auto property initializes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), ex: `public string example {get;} = "some example";`